# Issue with array_filter

Tags: php

```
$files = array_filter(scandir($dir), function($item) {
    return !is_dir('../folder/pictures/3/' . $item);
});

echo("<pre>".print_r($files,true)."</pre>");
```

I need to scan a directory but I only need file names and not folders. The code above works great, however when I use it in this way it stops working?

```
$dir    = "..".$config[picurl]."/".$pic_id;

$files = array_filter(scandir($dir), function($item) {
    return !is_dir($dir .'/'. $item);
});
```

Why can't I use the variable $dir?

Comment: change to `function($item) use ($dir){`  Because `$dir` is defined global, not in the function, so you have to give it as argument.

Comment: @Dan I hope my solution will help you out.